# Lollipop 5.0 bug with background services with notification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I just found this [article](http://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-bug-apps-frequently-restart-in-background), more specifically this sentence 
`"Unfortunately, people are reporting that their Lollipop isn't managing memory effectively, and background apps (even those with persistent notifications) are being closed unnecessarily."`
Can anyone tell me if this bug is still present? It's about the Nexus with Lollipop. 
I need to know, since I have an app, with foreground service notification, which have this exact same bug, notification disappearing and app not working.

Comment: I can confirm Lollipop does eat up a lot of memory. There must be memory leaks in os.

Comment: good, can some more people confirm on this please?

Comment: Google feels too succesful with Android's success to worry about such petty things. It is up to us, develpers, to come up with workarounds. Since Lollipop more than ever.